# is there a tool or package that allow image downloading in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have a scenario where when I click on preview image I want to add download option to that image, and to be able to work on both IOS/Android.

Is there any package or library that provide this ? Or is there another way to do this

Answer (score 0):

For expo app, on iOS you can save it to local storage (expo fileSystem), and then invoke "Sharing" api method (well documented on rn docs). For android you could use StorageAccessFramework from expo to create file, and then save it using expo fileSystem **writeAsStringAsync**.